# Error "Missing syntax element" while adding SPICE model in TINA software

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, spice, error, tina

I am trying to add a SPICE model for an AD8606 IC as it is not available in the existing library of TINA software.

[image]

But it is showing me an error, please help me to resolve it.

The error message in the above image reads:

```
Missing syntax element. Line #5.
REVISION HISTORY:
```

SPICE model for the AD8606 is:

```
* AD8606 SPICE Macro-model
* Description: Amplifier
* Generic Desc: 2.7/5V, CMOS, OP, Low Noise, RRIO, 2X
* Developed by: ADSJ-HH
Revision History: 
* 2.0  (05/2016) - Fixed flicker noise model - Emman.A (ADGT)
* Revision History: 08/10/2012 - Updated to new header style
* 1.0 (05/2002) - from AD8601-3/00v1
* Copyright 2010, 2012 by Analog Devices
*
* Refer to http://www.analog.com/Analog_Root/static/techSupport/designTools/spiceModels/license/spice_general.html for License Statement. Use of this model 
* indicates your acceptance of the terms and provisions in the License Statement.
*
* BEGIN Notes:
*
* Not Modeled:
*    
* Parameters modeled include: 
*
* END Notes
*
* Node Assignments
*           noninverting input
*           |   inverting input
*           |   |    positive supply
*           |   |    |   negative supply
*           |   |    |   |   output
*           |   |    |   |   |
*           |   |    |   |   |
.SUBCKT AD8606          1   2   99  50  45
* 
* INPUT STAGE
*
M1  14  7  8  8 PIX L=1E-6 W=1600E-6
M2  16  2  8  8 PIX L=1E-6 W=1600E-6
M3  17  7 10 10 NIX L=1E-6 W=1600E-6
M4  18  2 10 10 NIX L=1E-6 W=1600E-6
RC5 14 50 4E+3
RC6 16 50 4E+3
RC7 99 17 4E+3
RC8 99 18 4E+3
C1  14 16 0.6E-12
C2  17 18 0.6E-12
I1  99  8 100E-6
I2  10 50 100E-6
V1  99  9 0.3
V2  13 50 0.3
D1   8  9 DX
D2  13 10 DX
EOS  7  1 POLY(3) (22,98) (73,98) (81,98) 10E-6 1 1 1
IOS  1  2 0.05E-12
*
* CMRR 100dB,  POLE AT 4.5KHz
*
ECM1 21 98 POLY(2) (1,98) (2,98) 0 0.5 0.5
CCM1 21 22 3.54E-10
RCM1 21 22 100E3
RCM2 22 98 1
*
* PSRR=95dB, ZERO AT 534Hz
*
EPSY 98 72 POLY(1) (99,50) 0 1
CPS3 72 73 5.30E-9
RPS3 72 73 56234
RPS4 73 98 1
*
*
* VOLTAGE NOISE REFERENCE OF 8nV/rt(Hz)
*
VN1 80 98 0
RN1 80 98 16.45E-3
HN  81 98 VN1 5.8
RN2 81 98 1
*
* INTERNAL VOLTAGE REFERENCE
*
EREF 98  0 POLY(2) (99,0) (50,0) 0 .5 .5
GSY  99 50 (99,50) 48E-6 
EVP  97 98 POLY(1) (99,50) -0.6 0.5
EVN  51 98 POLY(1) (50,99) 0.6 0.5
*
* GAIN STAGE
*
G1 98 30 POLY(2) (14,16) (17,18) 0 56.3E-6 56.3E-6
R1 30 98 5.43E8
CF 45 30 9E-12
D3 30 97 DX
D4 51 30 DX
*
* OUTPUT STAGE
*
M5  45 46 99 99 POX L=1E-6 W=1.08E-3
M6  45 47 50 50 NOX L=1E-6 W=1.61E-3
EG1 99 46 POLY(1) (98,30) 0.4644 1
EG2 47 50 POLY(1) (30,98) 0.4394 1
*
* MODELS
*
.MODEL POX PMOS (LEVEL=2,KP=10E-6,VTO=-0.328,LAMBDA=0.01,RD=0)
.MODEL NOX NMOS (LEVEL=2,KP=10E-6,VTO=+0.328,LAMBDA=0.01,RD=0)
.MODEL PIX PMOS (LEVEL=2,KP=10E-6,VTO=-0.328,LAMBDA=0.01,KF=0.045E-31,AF=1,TOX=100E-3)
.MODEL NIX NMOS (LEVEL=2,KP=10E-6,VTO=+0.328,LAMBDA=0.01,KF=0.045E-31,AF=1,TOX=100E-3)
.MODEL DX D(IS=1E-14,RS=5)
.ENDS AD8606
*
*
```

Answer (score 7):

Comments are prefixed with an asterisk ('*').

The 5th line is obviously a comment, but the prefix is missing.

Change that line to

`* Revision History:`

and you should be good.

---

EDIT

*Analog Devices* has acknowledged this issue, though it's not resolved yet:
https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice/f/q-a/566533/ad8606-spice-model-seems-flawed/484209

Comment: It is resolved, Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @maxpro - Hi, If your comment means that your problem has been solved, then please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" the answer which was [the best solution for you](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the grey "tick mark" next to that answer to turn it green). This shows that the topic is solved, you don't need more help and future readers can quickly see which was the confirmed solution. Thanks.

Comment: (Note to other site members - please don't flag the OP's comment on this answer, since I refer to it in my comment above and we're waiting for a response from the OP. The comments will be tidied in due course. Thanks.)